# How to suppress "formatting is specified but argument is not iformattable" message for special methods

Tags: c#, vb.net, resharper

ReSharpers `StringFormatMethodAttribute` is a great way to keep track of the arguments on methods which perform string formatting.

So I implemented a method that way:

```cs
[StringFormatMethod("format")]
public string Format(string format, params object[] args)
{
    // do formatting by custom formatters
}
```

This gives me the ability to do things like that

```cs
Format("Hello {0}!", world);      // => Hello world!
Format("({0:D2} / {1:D2}", 2, 3); // => (02/03)
```

or in Visual Basic

```vb
Format("Hello {0}!", visualBasic) ' => Hello Visual Basic!
```

while ReSharper warns me if I miss an argument or its position like so

```cs
Format("Hello {1}!", world);
            // ^--- Non-existing argument in format string

Format("Hello {1}!", world, value);
                    // ^--- Argument is not used in format string
```

The method is using an `ICustomFormatter` so if I'd do this directly

```cs
string.Format(customFormatter, "The thread id is {0:D}", Thread.CurrentThread);
```

ReSharper does not complain.

Using my method, which uses the custom formatting internally however, makes ReSharper complain with a warning

```cs
Format("The thread id is {0:D}", Thread.CurrentThread);
                         // ^--- Formatting is specified,
                         //      but argument is not IFormattable
```

I don't want to disable this warnings in general, only the formatting issue part and if possible only for my own written methods. So my question is, is there a way, maybe by another attribute to make ReSharper aware, that this method is using a custom formatter internally?

Answer (score 1):

As you (guessing from the user name) learned [from a post on the JetBrains developer forum](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/473823) by [citizenmatt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88374/citizenmatt),

> Unfortunately, you can't disable this analysis. I've added a feature
>   request, which you can vote for, track and add any extra details:
>   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-450291